# How far are we from a black hole?

Tags: black-hole, resource-request, initial-mass-function

As far as I know, the closest (object reasonably believed to be a) black hole to Earth is [Gaia BH1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_BH1) at ~1560 ly. But presumably most black holes are hard to detect and there are undiscovered black holes closer. Knowing what we know about the [IMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_mass_function) and stellar evolution, how close can we reasonably expect to be to some black hole?

Comment: The duplicate gives the answer 18 parsecs or about 60 light years.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-far-away-is-the-nearest-compact-star-remnant-likely-to-be