# How could we search for old cold neutron stars?

Tags: neutron-star

This is the inverse of [Will Gaia detect inactive neutron stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16578/will-gaia-detect-inactive-neutron-stars) (to which the answer was "probably not").

So if Gaia can't do it, what would it take? How could such a search work, and what technological advances would be needed to have a reasonable chance of it working?

Comment: Highly relevant to any answer: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-far-away-is-the-nearest-compact-star-remnant-likely-to-be

Comment: Steve, old neutron stars don't have to be cold. So are you specifically talking about the ones that are? e.g. There could be a chance of detecting soft X-rays emitted by an old neutron star accreting from the interstellar medium. But that wouldn't be cold (or some of it wouldn't be anyway).

Comment: Supernova explosions can be rather asymmetrical, which can give the neutron star (or black hole) remnant quite a kick. One of the fastest known neutron stars is pulsar B1508+55, which has a speed around 1000 km/s relative to its neighbourhood. See https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0509031. An old cold neutron star won't lose much of its natal speed. So we just need to look for lensing events caused by dense objects with large proper motion...

Comment: @RobJeffries Not too worried about cold, although I guess it would be interesting to see one that was relatively quiescent compared to a pulsar.